# Checking 2 files in Unix and finding the sum of a particular column in 3rd file through shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, ksh

I have something I need help with, would appreciate your help 
Let's take an example

I have **file 1** with data

```
"eno", "ename", "salary"
"1","john","50000"
"2","steve","30000"
"3","aku","20000"
```

and I have **file 2** with data

```
"eno", "ename", "incentives"
"1","john","2000"
"2","steve","5000"
"4","akshi","200"
```

And the expected output in 3 file I want is :

```
"eno", "ename", "t_salary"
"1","john","52000"
"2","steve","35000"
```

This is what is expected result

as I should be using eno and the ename as the primary key and output should be shown like this

Comment: Hi Sir, I agree with your point that SO is not a coding service but I am unable to think over this, I only know how to use awk on one file and find similar results like this but how to do it with 2 files is something I am unable to apply logic on

Comment: Would really appreciate if you can give me at least some idea on how to achieve this task, thanks

Comment: The condition `FNR == NR` will tell you if you're processing the first file or the second file. When you're in the first file, save the line in an array. When you're in the second file, add column 3 to the value from the array element.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to know about the multiple files. Just use the employee number as the key in the array, and add the value in column 3 to it.

Comment: Actually I have to use eno and also the ename as the primary keys to compare in both the files

Comment: does the "eno" and "ename", count and value same acroess the 2 files ?

Answer (score 1):

if your files are sorted and first field is the key, you can `join` the files and work on the combined fields

that is,

```
$ join -t, file1 file2
"eno", "ename", "salary", "ename", "incentives"
"1","john","50000","john","2000"
"2","steve","30000","steve","5000"
```

and your `awk` can be

```
... | awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==1{print ...}
                         NR>1{gsub(/"/,"",$3); 
                              gsub(/"/,"",$5); 
                              print $1,$2,$3+$5}'
```

printing header and quoting the total field is left as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I tried the solutions but when I am taking a row different in file 1 and a row different in file 2, it is still combining the rows and showing the answer with some wrong calculations, actually I did this

Comment: I have file 1 with data

"eno", "ename", "salary"
"1","john","50000"
"2","steve","30000" "3","aku","20000"
and I have file 2 with data

"eno", "ename", "incentives"
"1","john","2000"
"2","steve","5000" "3","akshi","200"And the expected output in 3 file I want is :

"eno", "ename", "t_salary"
"1","john","52000"
"2","steve","35000"

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="\"[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*\""; OFS="\",\"" }
{ key = $1 FS $2 }
NR==FNR { sal[key] = $NF; next }
key in sal { $3 = (FNR>1 ? $3+sal[key] : "t_salary") "\""; print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
"eno","ename","t_salary"
"1","john","52000"
"2","steve","35000"
```

Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I tried the solutions but when I am taking a row different in file 1 and a row different in file 2, it is still combining the rows and showing the answer with some wrong calculations, actually I did this

Comment: I have file 1 with data

"eno", "ename", "salary"
"1","john","50000"
"2","steve","30000" "3","aku","20000"
and I have file 2 with data

"eno", "ename", "incentives"
"1","john","2000"
"2","steve","5000" "3","akshi","200"And the expected output in 3 file I want is :

"eno", "ename", "t_salary"
"1","john","52000"
"2","steve","35000"

Comment: Hi Ed, I have edited my question, Could you please help, sorry for inputs I gave in comments section, Apologies

Comment: Ed Sir I again had a query could you please explain me this code so that next time I would be able to put some more logic in it and try it by myself and yes thanks for the book suggestion I am surely reading it

Comment: Sorry but no, this is all basic awk and I was willing to post it despite you not having posted your own attempt in your question so you'd have something to google and look up in the awk book I mentioned to figure out how it works for yourself and learn a lot more in the process. Once you do that if you have specific questions I'll be happy to answer them.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ed and the suggestion, I will surely clear my doubts and will be in regular contact

Answer (score 0):

Abbreviating the input files to *f1* & *f2*, and breaking out the swiss army knife utils, (plus a *bash*ism):

```
head -n 1 f1 | sed 's/sal/t_&/' ; \
grep -h -f <(tail -qn +2 f1 f2 | tr ',' '\t' | sort -k1,2 | \
             rev | uniq -d -f1 | rev | \
             cut -f 2) \
      f1 f2 | \
tr -s ',"' '\t' | datamash -s -g2,3 sum 4 | sed 's/[^\t]*/"&"/g;s/\t/,/g'
```

Output:

```
"eno", "ename", "t_salary"
"1","john","52000"
"2","steve","35000"
```

---

The main job is fairly simple:

1. `grep` searches for only those lines with duplicate (and therefore add-able) fields #1 & #2, and this is piped to...
2. `datamash` which does the adding.

The rest of the code is reformatting needed to please the various text utils which all seem to have *ugly*  but minor format inconsistencies.

Those `rev`s are only needed because `uniq` lacks most of `sort`'s field functions.

The `tr`s are because `uniq` also lacks a field separator switch, and `datamash` can't sum quoted numbers.  The `sed` at the end is to undo all that `tr`-ing.